# Opening a HDFS file in browser

Tags: firefox, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I am trying to open a file (present in the HDFS location: /user/input/Summary.txt) in my browser using the URL:  hdfs://localhost:8020/user/input/Summary.txt but I am getting an error in my firefox browser:

`Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (hdfs) isn't associated with any program.`

If I change the protocol from `hdfs` to `http` (which ideally should not work) then I am getting the message: `It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port. This is not the correct port for the web interface on this daemon.`

This is present in the `core-site.xml` file:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>
```

Please let me know how to make this work. I am not sure whether the problem is related to firefox browser OR I am missing some configuration settings OR i am using the incorrect url.

**EDIT:**

When I try to access it from a java code, i get an exception: `unknown protocol: hdfs`.

```
static{
    URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new FsUrlStreamHandlerFactory());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    final String url = "hdfs://localhost:8020/user/input/Summary.txt";

    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();

}
```

Please suggest how to access the `hdfs protocol` from java code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HDFS 8020 is IPC port, you need to open HDFS Web UI for HDFS browser, It's default port is 50070, Open following URL from your Web Browser

`http://localhost:50070/` , then Go to `Live nodes` option -> Select one of your datanodes from there -> Click on Browse filesystem

Comment: is it like we cant open an IPC port directly from my browser? In that case, can I read the Summary.txt file from my java code (using the URL class) ?

Comment: You canno t open IPC port from browser, that's possible you can read the files from Java. While creating instance of Path you can define the path as follows

Path inFile = new Path(hdfs://localhost:8020/dir1/file1.txt);

Comment: in hadoop version >3.0.0 the port was changed to 9870