# Image/Video on HBASE and made available via some sort of Http URL for access

Tags: rest, hadoop, binary, streaming, hbase

I want to store some videos[binary] files on HBase,and made available via some sort of Http URL for access.
Can someone help me with the architecture/design for such uses cases.

I have seen below links, mostly referring to HDFS; Is HDFS better for this kind of usecase as compared to HBase?

https://www.quora.com/Is-hadoop-HDFS-a-type-of-system-you-use-to-store-videos-for-your-internet-application

[Store images/videos into Hadoop HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546040/store-images-videos-into-hadoop-hdfs)

[Accessing video stored in HDFS over http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451685/accessing-video-stored-in-hdfs-over-http)

Answer (score 0):

after 5 years since you asked your question , I think there is no way to store images or videos in HBase , indeed Hbase is used for NoSQL data storage on top of HDFS... the optimal way is store images and videos in HDFS directly;
to conclude : HDFS is best choice for this usecase !

Comment: Yes, we choose to keep videos on hdfs and hdfs links for those video stored on HBase.

Comment: yes it was a POC